# accessing specific itemview in listview in button onclick method

Tags: java, android, listview, textview

```html
public class DisplayAllBets extends ActionBarActivity {
    private String user1 = "user";
    private static String url_all_games = "**";
    private static String url_update_bet = "**";

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private ProgressDialog tDialog;
    private BetDisplayer currentitem;
    private HashMap<String, String> userhash = new HashMap<>();

    private ArrayList<BetDisplayer> listwriter = new ArrayList<>();
    private HashMap<String, String> useroutcomes = new HashMap<>();
    private HashMap<String, String> finalhash = new HashMap<>();

    private ArrayList<Map<String, String>> passtocheck = new ArrayList<>();
    private HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> passtocheckver2 = new HashMap<>();
    private String name;
    private HashMap<String, String> allopens = new HashMap<>();
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();


    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParsers jParser = new JSONParsers();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> bet;

    // url to get all products list

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_BET = "bet";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_STAKE = "stake";
    private static final String TAG_USER = "user";
    private static final String TAG_RETURNS = "returns";
    private static final String TAG_TEAMS = "teams";
    private static final String TAG_STATUS = "status";


    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray allgames = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_all_bets);


        name = (getIntent().getExtras().getString("user")).toLowerCase();
        Log.d("name", name);
        // Hashmap for ListView
        bet = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllGames().execute();

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     */
    class LoadAllGames extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        private String id;
        private String stake;
        private String user;
        private String returns;
        private String teams;
        private String status;


        //  *//**
        //   * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
        //    *//*
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(DisplayAllBets.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Games. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        }

        //  *//**
        //    * getting All products from url
        //    *//*
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url_all_games);
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", name));
            try {
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                Log.d("Http Post Response:", response.toString());
                HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream is = httpEntity.getContent();
                JSONObject jObj = null;
                String json = "";
                try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                        if (!line.startsWith("<", 0)) {
                            if (!line.startsWith("(", 0)) {
                                sb.append(line + "\n");
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    is.close();
                    json = sb.toString();
                    json = json.substring(json.indexOf('{'));
                    Log.d("sb", json);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
                }

                // try parse the string to a JSON object
                try {
                    jObj = new JSONObject(json);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
                }

                // return JSON String
                Log.d("json", jObj.toString());
                try {
                    allgames = jObj.getJSONArray(TAG_BET);
                    Log.d("allgames", allgames.toString());
                    ArrayList<BetDatabaseSaver> listofbets = new ArrayList<>();
                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < allgames.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = allgames.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String user = c.getString(TAG_USER);
                        String returns = c.getString(TAG_RETURNS);
                        String stake = c.getString(TAG_STAKE);
                        String status = c.getString(TAG_STATUS);
                        String Teams = c.getString(TAG_TEAMS);
                        Log.d("id", id);
                        Log.d("user", user);
                        Log.d("returns", returns);
                        Log.d("stake", stake);
                        Log.d("status", status);
                        Log.d("teams", Teams);


                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_TEAMS, Teams);
                        map.put(TAG_USER, user);
                        map.put(TAG_RETURNS, returns);
                        map.put(TAG_STAKE, stake);
                        map.put(TAG_STATUS, status);
                        if (status.equals("open")) {
                            useroutcomes.put(id.substring(0, 10), Teams);
                        }
                        listwriter.add(i, new BetDisplayer(user, id, Integer.parseInt(stake), Integer.parseInt(returns), status, Teams));


                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        bet.add(map);
                    }


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }


            return "";
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String param) {


            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            String ultparam = "";
            int i = 0;
            for (HashMap<String, String> a : bet) {
                String teams = a.get(TAG_TEAMS);

                Map<String, String> listofteams = new HashMap<>();

                Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[(](\\d+)/([1X2])[)]");
                Matcher m = p.matcher(teams);
                Log.d("printa", teams);
                while (m.find()) {
                    listofteams.put(m.group(1), m.group(2));
                }
                Log.d("dede", listofteams.toString());
                String c = "";
                for (String x : listofteams.keySet()) {
                    String b = x + ",";
                    c = c + b;
                }
                Log.d("C", c);
                c = c.substring(0, c.lastIndexOf(","));
                //    Log.d("Cproc", c);
                if (a.get(TAG_STATUS).equals("open")) {
                    ultparam = ultparam + a.get(TAG_ID).substring(0, 10) + c + "//";
                    passtocheck.add(listofteams);
                    allopens.put(Integer.toString(i), a.get(TAG_STATUS));
                    i++;
                }

                i++;

            }
            ultparam = ultparam.substring(0, ultparam.lastIndexOf("//"));
            Log.d("ULTPARAM", ultparam);
            CheckBet checker = new CheckBet(ultparam, passtocheck);
            HashMap<String, String> finaloutcomes = checker.checkbetoutcome();
            Log.d("Finaloutcomes", finaloutcomes.toString());
            for (String x : finaloutcomes.keySet()) {
                    for (int p = 0; p < listwriter.size(); p++) {
                        if (listwriter.get(p).getId().substring(0, 10).equals(x)) {
                            String[] finaloutcomearray = finaloutcomes.get(x).split(" ");
                            String[] useroutcomearray = listwriter.get(p).getSelections().split(" ");
                            for (int r = 0; r < finaloutcomearray.length; r++) {
                                Log.d("finaloutcomearray", finaloutcomearray[r]);
                                Log.d("useroutcomearray", useroutcomearray[r]);
                                String[] indfinaloutcomesarray = finaloutcomearray[r].split("\\)");
                                String[] induseroutcomearray = useroutcomearray[r].split("\\)");
                                for (int d = 0; d < indfinaloutcomesarray.length; d++) {
                                    Log.d("indfinaloutcome", indfinaloutcomesarray[d]);
                                    Log.d("induseroutcome", induseroutcomearray[d]);
                                    finalhash.put(indfinaloutcomesarray[d].substring(1, indfinaloutcomesarray[d].lastIndexOf("/")), indfinaloutcomesarray[d].substring(indfinaloutcomesarray[d].lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
                                    userhash.put(induseroutcomearray[d].substring(1, induseroutcomearray[d].lastIndexOf("/")), induseroutcomearray[d].substring(induseroutcomearray[d].lastIndexOf("/") + 1));

                                }
                            }
                            Log.d("FINALHASHfinal", finalhash.toString());
                            Log.d("USERHASHfinal", userhash.toString());
                            listwriter.get(p).setStatus("won");
                            for (String id : userhash.keySet()) {
                                if (finalhash.get(id).equals("null")){
                                    listwriter.get(p).setStatus("open");
                                }
                                else if (!(finalhash.get(id).equals(userhash.get(id)))) {
                                    listwriter.get(p).setStatus("lost");
                                    break;
                                }

                            }
                            finalhash.clear();
                            userhash.clear();
                        currentitem = listwriter.get(p);
                           new UpdateBetStatus().execute();
                        }
                    }
                }

            Log.d("USEROUTCOMES", useroutcomes.toString());


            PopulateList();

        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_display_all_bets, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    class UpdateBetStatus extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * *
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            tDialog = new ProgressDialog(DisplayAllBets.this);
            tDialog.setMessage("Loading your bets! Good luck!");
            tDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            tDialog.setCancelable(true);
        }

        /**
         * Creating product
         * *
         */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {


            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", currentitem.getId()));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stake", Integer.toString(currentitem.getStake())));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("returns", Integer.toString(currentitem.getReturns())));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("teams", currentitem.getSelections()));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("status", currentitem.getStatus()));


            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_update_bet,
                    "POST", params);

            // check log cat fro response
            Log.d("Printing", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * * * *
         */
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done

        }
    }


    private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BetDisplayer> {
        public MyListAdapter() {
            super(DisplayAllBets.this, R.layout.activity_singletotalbet, listwriter);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View itemView = convertView;
            if (itemView == null) {
                itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_singletotalbet, parent, false);
            }
            BetDisplayer currentwriter = listwriter.get(position);
            Log.d("TESTING", currentwriter.getSelections());
            Button v = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.detailsbutton);
            v.setTag(Integer.toString(position));
            Log.d("TESTING2", currentwriter.getSelections());
            String selections = currentwriter.getSelections();
            int numberofselections = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < selections.length(); i++) {
                if (selections.charAt(i) == '/') {
                    numberofselections++;
                }
            }
            if (numberofselections == 1) {
                TextView descriptor = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.no);
                descriptor.setText("Single");
            } else if (numberofselections == 2) {
                TextView descriptor = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.no);
                descriptor.setText("Double");
            } else if (numberofselections == 3) {
                TextView descriptor = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.no);
                descriptor.setText("Treble");
            } else {
                TextView descriptor = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.no);
                descriptor.setText("Accumulator" + "(" + numberofselections + ")");
            }
            TextView status = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.status);
            status.setText(currentwriter.getStatus());
            return itemView;
        }
    }

    private void PopulateList() {
        ArrayAdapter<BetDisplayer> adapter = new MyListAdapter();
        final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.betslistviews);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
           public void Viewdetails(View v) {
           Button b = (Button) v;
           int position = Integer.parseInt((String) v.getTag());
           final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.betslistviews);
           String stake;
           String winnings;
           String token;
           String teams;
           String typeofbet;
           list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

               public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) {

                   TextView status = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.status);
                   Log.d("STATUSTESTING",status.getText().toString());

               }
       });
    }
```

I have a populated listview. Each item in the list contains a button and a few TextViews, in the following format.

[image]

I created a method which is run when any of the buttons is clicked. What I need it to do is to retrieve that particular itemView at that position in the listview so I can access the TextViews in that itemview. This is my code but it isn't working atm.

```html
  public void Viewdetails(View v) {
       Button b = (Button) v;
       int position = Integer.parseInt((String) v.getTag());
       final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.betslistviews);
       String stake;
       String winnings;
       String token;
       String teams;
       String typeofbet;
       list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) {

               View selItem = (View) list.getItemAtPosition(position);
               TextView status = (TextView) selItem.findViewById(R.id.status);
               Log.d("STATUSTESTING",status.getText().toString());

           }
   });
}
```

Comment: show full activity code

Comment: @AntonKovalyov ok updated it, the relevant code is mostly on the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your ListView listener starts here.

```
   list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) {

           View selItem = (View) list.getItemAtPosition(position);
           TextView status = (TextView) selItem.findViewById(R.id.status);
           Log.d("STATUSTESTING",status.getText().toString());

       }
  });
```

You don't have to write

```
View selItem = (View) list.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

since you already got reference to the particular View in ListView from the overridden onItemClick method.

So you can skip that line and directly access TextView

```
TextView status = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.status);
```

Finally the code will be like

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) {

           //Already got reference to View v
           TextView status = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.status);
           Log.d("STATUSTESTING",status.getText().toString());

       }
  });
```

Comment: I still get no output in the logcat when I press the button

Answer (score 0):

To catch onListItemClick add listener in `PopulateList()` method:

```
private void PopulateList() {
        ArrayAdapter<BetDisplayer> adapter = new MyListAdapter();
        final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.betslistviews);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) {
               // Change children of list item here
               TextView status = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.status);
               Log.d("STATUSTESTING",status.getText().toString());

           }
        });
    }
```

To catch click on button in your list item you need in your adapter's `getView()` method add click listener to button:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Button v = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.detailsbutton);
    v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           // Handle button click

       }
    });
}
```

**EDIT:**

To store data create fields in Activity and setters for it:

```
private String text1;
private String text2;

public void setText1(String text){
    text1 = text;
}

public void setText2(String text){
    text2 = text;
}
```

Then set it in button click listener:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView tv1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview1_id);
        TextView tv2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview2_id);
        Button v = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.detailsbutton);
        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               setText1(tv1.getText());
               setText2(tv2.getText());
           }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, on button click I want to retrieve all the data from that itemView and do some things to it. When I put the `TextView status = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.status);
               Log.d("STATUSTESTING",status.getText().toString());` in the onItemClick method, nothing happens but when it is in the onClick method for the button, it prints out the statuses as expected, however it doesn't print out the correct ones, it seems to randomly toggle between the 3 possible options of 'open' 'won' 'lost' -  that happens if I type `itemView.findViewbyId`,otherwise it always prints 'open'

Comment: can you explain more specific what you need to achieve?

Comment: Let's say we have 2 itemViews in the listView. The first one is `Single    Open     (Button:Details)` the second one is `Treble    Lost    (Button:Details`. What I need is that when I click on the button in the first itemview it will retrieve Single,Open for me and store them in string variables. And if I click on the button in the second itemview it will retrieve treble,Lost and do the same.

Comment: basically retrieving the data from the TextViews ^

Comment: I think the problem is that if you look at my getView method, I set the values of the descriptor and status TextViews there and when you scroll through the listView, this method is called again and the values are reset which creates the problem. Is there a way to do this whole process in a method outside of the listView adapter using the android:onClick property? This is what I did in another class :  `public void clicking(View v) {
        Button b = (Button) v;
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) v.getParent();` Then i worked with layout.findViewby

Comment: If by `set the values` you mean this code `BetDisplayer currentwriter = listwriter.get(position);` then just move it to button click.

Comment: I mean this code : `TextView status = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.status);
            status.setText(currentwriter.getStatus());` and this code `TextView descriptor = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.no);
                descriptor.setText("Double");`